# Rename "show XX entries" drop down in DataTables

Tags: jquery, datatables

In DataTables is there any way to rename the Show ___ Entries drop down text?  Specifically, I have a client who wants to change "Show" to "Display". If memory serves, this is generated by the lengthMenu item, but while I see how to customize the select box options I haven't found any way to change the label.

UPDATE: here is my relevant code.

```
$("#datatable").dataTable( {
  bFilter: false,
  "sDom": 'lfptip',
  "oLanguage": {
    "sLengthMenu": "Display _MENU_ records",
  }
  "aoColumnDefs": [{ "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [ 9 ] }, { sType: 'datetime-us-flex', aTargets: [0, 4] }, { sType: 'numeric-empty-bottom', aTargets: [7, 8] },
    { "sClass": "col-strong", "aTargets": [ 1 ] }
  ],
});
```

Comment: https://datatables.net/plug-ins/i18n/English lists all available translation keys. Did you try to modify that one?

Comment: You're missing a comma after the first closing brace (and you have an extra one after the last closing bracket). The console should've alerted you to that fact.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use this

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
    "oLanguage": {
      "sLengthMenu": "Display _MENU_ records",
    }
});
```

from  https://datatables.net/docs/DataTables/1.9.beta.1/DataTable.defaults.oLanguage.html#sLengthMenu_details

Answer (score 5):

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
    "oLanguage": {
      "sLengthMenu": "Your words here _MENU_ and/or here",
    }
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/pg5s1ctf/2) | [**Docs**](https://datatables.net/docs/DataTables/1.9.beta.1/DataTable.defaults.oLanguage.html#sLengthMenu_details)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#table_id').DataTable({
 "oLanguage": {
                 "sLengthMenu": "Display _MENU_ records", // **dont remove _MENU_ keyword**
            },

});
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.