# What are the best ways to implement a dynamic matrix report using APEX?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, report, oracle-apex

I need to complete this task using Oracle Application Express framework.

Let's say we have such a query:

```
select   
  col1,  
  col2,  
  val1,  
  val2,  
  val3,  
  val4,  
  val5,  
  val6,  
  val7,  
  val8,  
  val9,  
  val10,  
  val11  
from table(mega_function(city => ?, format => ?, percent => ?, days => ?));
```

And this query returns something like this (shown in CSV format):

```
col1;col2;val1;val2;val3;val4;val5;val6;val7;val8;val9;val10;val11
S2;C1;32000;120;"15:38:28";1450;120;1500;1200;31000;120;32600;300
S1;C1;28700;120;"15:35:01";150;120;1500;1800;2700;60;28900;120
S1;C2;27000;240;"14:44:23";0;1500;240;1200;25500;60;null;null
```

To put it simple, the query bases on a pipelined function which takes some parameters and returns some set of values for different pairs of values of first two columns `col1;col2`.

What I need to implement is a matrix report where values of `col1` are used as rows of the report and values of `col2` as columns. On the intersection there are cells which contain set of values for the pair with some formatting and styles applied. What is also needed - is sorting by rows (which should sort columns by values of the column 'val1').

Or if we show the above needs on a mockup:
[image: mockup]

**So the question is - what are the best practises to implement such a matrix report with some interaction and custom styles?**

What I have already tried to look into:

- Interactive Report Pivot functionality (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E71588_01/AEEUG/managing-pivot-reports.htm#AEEUG29137) - lacks customization, works badly with many values, especially when they are not numbers.
- Classic report based on Function - I have implemented [PL/SQL function](https://pastebin.com/B07yEKg2) which returns dynamic PIVOT SQL query, in the properties of the report `Use Generic Column Names` set to `Yes` (in order to parse the query only in runtime) and for headings of the report I used another [PL/SQL function](https://pastebin.com/0rFZjexZ), which generates a string in the format `heading1:headning2:...:headingN`. 
  The solution works (you can check it here - https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=132832:2), but I need to refresh the report dynamically every, let's say, 5 seconds, and it will suck in terms of performance (dynamic SQL is always bad and not managable way if we talk about execution plans). Also this solution doesn't fit, because headings are not concerted with the data (actually I used `order by col1` in the queries in both PL/SQL functions to make headings be in their places) and I don't know how to make rows sortable here.
- PL/SQL Dynamic Content Region - I haven't tried to code something here, but I realise that it's possible to do anything here just using HTP package and APEX API. The tricky thing is this solution is quite complex, I'll need to implement all the logic of the report 'from scratch' and I believe there's a better and easier way to succeed in the task, which I don't know.

Comment: To clarify the task more - it would be splendind, if I could manipulate the data on the presentation level - without rewriting the query just implement the markup in a desirable way, but I don't know how to do it so far.

Comment: What Version of Oracle APEX are you using? APEX 5.1 has the new interactive grids. They may be able to help you, though I am not sure whether they can build that pivoted view you want. Saving the data is probably the easiest part, since you can always use some PLSQL for that. The only option that is guaranteed to work is a dynamic content region, though you will have to most of it yourself then.

Comment: I am using APEX 5.1, and I've estimated IGs already, but it lacks functionality of PIVOTing out of the box, and I don't know if it can have it. The only thing that I heard about IGs is that they are rendered on the client, and data is given to them in JSON, so it looks like they could be hacked using JavaScript. Howewer, I also don't think it's the easiest way to succeed.

Comment: Yes, the whole IG is based on a sophisticated, but totally undocumented Model-View-Controller architecture. Look out for the javascript library `apex.model` if you want to go that path, though you will not find many sources.

Comment: Both 2nd and 3rd options are correct in this case. But if you feel that in dynamic PL/SQL region  generating HTML for table is little complex then you can try [datatables](https://datatables.net/examples/index) API. Even I had the similar case where I used AJAX OnDemand Process to load the data into tables(datatables). It is very fast and you get plenty of options, I would say better then classic report.

Comment: @Himanshujaggi, I don't like my second solution because I'd rather query the data from DB in JSON format and then put this data in apropriate way on the page (I suppose IGs do the same job out-of-the-box, but they're weakly documented). Am I right that [datatables](https://datatables.net/) are exactly for this purpose? Are there any other options to do so?

Comment: Future readers: question also present in OTN https://community.oracle.com/message/14472162?

Comment: @Himanshujaggi, thank you for your tip about DataTables, composed an answer using this approach.

Comment: I'd add one more option which is to create a collection or use a sort of temporary table as an intermediary so the Apex report is based on something less complicated than your matrix/pivot SQL. Intermediate data store also makes it easier to debug since you can focus on the Page to Intermediary separate from the Intermediary to Source Data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, none of the options I mentioned in the question met all the requirements because of the conditions in which report will live:

- Data should be dynamically updated every, let's say, 5 seconds.
- State of the report should be saved over data updates.
- Number of columns of the report is variable (definition of columns is 
  provided with data), number of rows is variable as well. Report should have 
  sorting, pagination and scrolling (by X and Y) options. All the stuff
  (sorting, etc.) should be done on client-side.
- Styles and custom cell rendering should be applied to cells of the table.
- Cells should be clickable (click should generate an event, which is 
  interceptable).

I realized that for such a task it's better to manipulate DOM on-the-fly on client-side instead of using some out-of-the-box APEX solutions like classic reports, interactive reports or grids.

I used [DataTables.js](https://datatables.net/) jQuery plugin for this approach. After a week of estimating the technology and learning some basic JavaScript (which is not my primary skill), I had the following:

In the APEX application I implemented an Ajax Callback process (called `TEST_AJAX`), it runs PL/SQL code, which returns JSON-object to `SYS.HTP` output (using `APEX_JSON` or `HTP` packages). Its source:

```
declare 
    l_temp sys_refcursor;
begin  
    open l_temp for go_pivot;
    APEX_JSON.open_object;
    APEX_JSON.open_array('columns');
    APEX_JSON.open_object;
    APEX_JSON.write('data', 'COL2');
    APEX_JSON.write('title', '/');
    APEX_JSON.close_object;
    for x in (select distinct col1 from test order by 1) loop
        APEX_JSON.open_object;
        APEX_JSON.write('data', upper(x.col1));
        APEX_JSON.write('title', x.col1);
        APEX_JSON.close_object;
    end loop;
    APEX_JSON.close_array;
    APEX_JSON.write('data', l_temp); 
    APEX_JSON.close_object;
end;
```

The `go_pivot` function source:

```
create or replace function go_pivot return varchar2
  is
      l_query long := 'select col2';
  begin
      for x in (select distinct col1 from test order by col1)
      loop
          l_query := l_query ||
             replace(', min(decode(col1,''$X$'',v)) $X$',
                      '$X$',
                     x.col1);
     end loop;
     l_query := l_query || ' from test group by col2';
    return l_query;
 end;
```

Then I created a Static Content region on the page, the source of which is following:

```html
<div id="datatable_test_container"></div>
```

I uploaded CSS and JS files of DataTables.js to application static files and included them in the page properties. In the `JavaScript` section of the page for `Function and Global Variable Declaration` I added this javascript code:

```js
var $ = apex.jQuery;
var table;
var columns;
var rows;

//table initialization function
function table_init(json_data) {
    return $('#datatable_test').DataTable({
        //column defaults options
        columnDefs: [{
            "data": null,
            "defaultContent": "-",
            "targets": "_all"
        }],
        columns: json_data.columns,
        data: json_data.data,
        stateSave: true
    });
}
//function to asynchronously get data from APEX AJAX CALLBACK
//process and then to draw a table based on this data
function worker() {
    //run the process called TEST_JSON
    apex.server.process(
        "TEST_JSON", {}, {
            success: function(pData) {
                //on first run we need to initialize the table
                if (typeof table == 'undefined') {
                    //save current data for future use
                    columns = $.extend(true, [], pData.columns);
                    rows = $.extend(true, [], pData.data);
                    //generate empty html-table in the container
                    $('#datatable_test_container').append('<table id = "datatable_test" class = "display" cellspacing = "0" width = "100%" > < /table>');
                    //init the table
                    table = table_init(pData);
                    //when columns of the table changes we need to 
                    //reinitialize the table (DataTables require it due to architecture)
                } else if (JSON.stringify(columns) !=
                    JSON.stringify(pData.columns)) {
                    //save current data for future use
                    columns = $.extend(true, [], pData.columns);
                    rows = $.extend(true, [], pData.data);
                    //delete the table from DOM
                    table.destroy(true);
                    //generate empty html-table in the container
                    $('#datatable_test_container').append('<table id = "datatable_test" class = "display" cellspacing = "0" width = "100%" > < /table>');
                    //reinit the table
                    table = table_init(pData);
                }
                //if data changes, clear and re-draw the table
                else if (JSON.stringify(rows) != JSON.stringify(pData.data)) {
                    //save current data for future use
                    //we don't need to save the columns, they didn't change
                    rows = $.extend(true, [], pData.data);
                    //clear table, add rows from recieved JSON-object, re-
                    draw the table with new data
                    table.clear().rows.add(pData.data).draw(false);
                }
                //if nothing changes, we do nothing
            }
        }
    );
    //repeat the procedure in a second
    setTimeout(worker, 1000);
};
```

For `Execute when Page Loads` I added:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    worker();
});
```

**What all this does:**

1. Static `<div>` in the static content region recieves an empty
   table    where DataTables constructor is applied.
2. JavaScript code starts its work by triggering the Ajax Callback server 
   process, and on success uses the result this process returned.
3. DataTables constructor supports different types of data sources, for example 
   it can parse an html-table or make an ajax-call, but I
   preferred to use an APEX process and then base the table on the
   JSON-object, which this process returns.
4. Then the script watches changes. If columns changes, the table is deleted 
   from the document and re-initialized using new data, if only rows changes, 
   then the table is just re-drawn with this data. If nothing changes in data
   then the script does nothing.
5. This process is repeated every second.

As a result, there's a totally interactive, being dynamically refreshed, report, with such options as sorting, paging, searching, event handling and so on. And all these is done on client-side without extra queries to server.

You can check the result using this [live demo](https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=132832:3)  (the top region is DataTables report, below it there's an editable interactive grid on the source table, to see the changes, you can change data using the interactive grid).

I don't know if this is the best approach, but it meets my requirements.

**UPDATED 05.09.2017:** Added listing of `APEX_JSON` Ajax Callback process and `go_pivot` PL/SQL function.

Comment: Well written. Definitely this will help others.

Comment: Thanks again for your suggestion.

Comment: @Himanshujaggi, now I'm stuck with a different issue - I added a test submit button on the page where I'm using DataTables, and now I get an exception `ERR-1002 Unable to find item ID for item "datatable_test_length" in application "%APPLICATION_ID%"` every time I submit the page (you can check it [here](https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=132832:3)). `datatable_test_length` item is defined by the DataTables core, and obciously it isn't defined in APEX. So, do you know any workarounds?

Comment: This looks strange, I am not able to reproduce the same error, just check if your code it trying to refer this item on page submit.

Comment: @Himanshujaggi, my code isn't trying to refer to any item on page submit, it's just a test submit button, actually I don't even have any existing process at `pocessing` point. It seems APEX just don't understand any dynamic HTML, generated by JavaSxript. The question is how to exclude these items from submit.

Comment: I just renamed item "datatable_test_length" to  "datatable_length" using developer tools and then submitted the page. It worked fine. Just try rename the same. By default APEX never maps the custom HTML items.

Comment: @Himanshujaggi, `datatable_test_length` is not my item, it's generated by DataTables core when you trigger `DataTables()` constructor. So I don't know how to rename this item, it's not controllable by me.

Comment: I understood your problem. Datatables API provide an option to rename item just try this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27788778/rename-show-xx-entries-drop-down-in-datatables) or else you can write your own JavaScript code to rename.

Comment: How you construct you're Ajax Process !! if you can elaborate or paste snippet here in above code! Or is it possible for you to make that application downloadable !

Comment: @PranavShah, I can export this page from my application if you like.

Comment: Sure. Or you can share developer credentials i'll have a quick look into it or export the whole app.

Comment: @PranavShah, I updated my answer - included listings for the functions mentioned.

Comment: Great now it's complete solution :-)

Answer (score -1):

You are correct. I only provided an opinion based on my early understanding of your description of requirements.. Now that I read that more carefully, I changed my mind cause I realized it's not a difficult matrix what you have.. In fact I have many of those..

I am not aware of best practices per se but I can share with you what I have done with similar requirements:

For matrix based reports I prefer classic Reports, I put my filtering criteria on the header section (just like in your mock) and based on the user selection the information changes very nicely. That's how I handle the filtering and Sorting.

The hardest part (IMO) with your requirements is the checking of cells for exporting purposes.. You should be able to enable a toggle control dynamically in your query and with a bit of AJAX you should be able to pickup the chosen ones for the exports.

Comment: As I already mentioned in the question, Classic Report on a PL/SQL Function doesn't meet the requirements - this approach is very slow, because all the logic is implemented in the dynamic SQL query on the backend. Dynamic SQL is hardly manageable itself, but the main problem is the fact that Classic Reports base on a result of a query, and it's impossible to re-draw it on-the-fly.

Answer (score -4):

Based on your requirements APEX is probably not the right tool, you'll be endlessly limited by the underlying libraries and capabilities of JQuery, etc.

I would not venture to develop such application on APEX, In my opinion the requirements are too far out for the technology offered in APEX.

On the other hand you talk about DB performance.. Good that you're taking that into consideration from the planning phase, but bad because you're limiting yourself already.. there are options... e.g. get an in-memory option in the database and/cache the results from a Materialized view.. Pin the tables to memory.

Comment: What do you mean not the right tool? They made oracle store, asktom.oracle.com, the APEX IDE itself using APEX, and you say that this tool is not apropriate for a matrix reporting task? Too far out for the technology offered in APEX? Another kind of a report (matrix report) is too far from the tool which offers several kinds of report regions out of the box? Even if so, it's always easy to say "Technology X sucks in Y, it's just not for such tasks", and you didn't suggest anything.

Comment: And talking about the performance - did you understand the task in general? Where are you going to use in-memory options or materialized views? How materialized views correlate with dynamic SQL? I mention performance ONLY because I used dynamic SQL in that solution, and it's not possible to materialize such a query or to put it into memory, because the query is different from occasion to occasion, the plan is different, the resultset is different. And I asked the question exactly because I see this is not the best way, and I don't want to use dynamic query here.